# Modelling nested states in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, state-machine, states

I haven't been able to find any documentation /tutorials/Q&As for how to model nested states in rails.

Is there a way to do this using the state_machine gem? (or another gem)

My specific situation is that I have an object which has a state. This can be:

```
'scheduled', 'on-shift' or 'past'
```

In addition, 'on-shift' can be of state:

```
'available', 'busy' or 'inactive'
```

How can I model these states?

Answer (score 0):

hard to know exactly what will work for you without more detail, but my instinct at this point would be to have 5 states: `%w(scheduled available busy inactive past)`

you could then have some additional methods to simulate the 'on-shift' state, eg:

```
def on_shift?
  %w(available busy inactive).include? state
end
```

(I'm assuming `state` is the current state, but if not you can replace it with however you access the object's current state.